# c++ double representation asm

Tags: c++, assembly, double

I have simple code like this example:

```
int main() {
  double i_3 = 4.1; // 8 bytes
  return 0;
}
```

Let's compile this sample with -S option:

```
g++ -S -o asm_types.s asm_types.cpp
```

Compiler returns .s file with following code:

```
    .file   "asm_types.cpp"
    .text
    .globl  main
    .type   main, @function
main:
.LFB0:
    .cfi_startproc
    pushq   %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
    .cfi_offset 6, -16
    movq    %rsp, %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa_register 6
    movabsq $4616302208045442662, %rax
    movq    %rax, -8(%rbp)
    movl    $0, %eax
    popq    %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa 7, 8
    ret
    .cfi_endproc
.LFE0:
    .size   main, .-main
    .ident  "GCC: (Ubuntu 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04) 4.8.4"
    .section    .note.GNU-stack,"",@progbits
```

I am trying to understand this line of .s file

```
movabsq $4616302208045442662, %rax
```

What is 4616302208045442662?

Thanks

Comment: It's a 64-bit integer immediate with the same bits set as the `double`-value you want.

Comment: See [binaryconvert](http://www.binaryconvert.com/result_double.html?decimal=052046049)

Comment: And don't forget that `printf '%x\n' 4616302208045442662` yields `4010666666666666`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You essentially want to read up on IEEE 754, and specifically how it stores (encodes) a value in binary. But in short, it breaks the number up into three main pieces (64-bits in this case):

- sign (1 bit)
- exponent (11 bits)
- fraction (52 bits)

The main question you are probably asking is how did something simple like 4.1 turn into so many random looking bits (4616302208045442662h). It is mainly a result of how the number is broken apart and *scaled*. The scaling is necessary to provide the equivalent number of [significant digits](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2006/06/16/634078.aspx) that can slide between very small numbers and very large numbers.

Readings:

- http://grouper.ieee.org/groups/754/faq.html
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer !